# Theoretically would this be faster?

Tags: mysql

I have a simple schema where users are messaging eachother.

```
id
sender_id
receiver_id
message
created_at
```

If I wanted to retrieve messages between two users (id:3 and id:7 for example), I would have to use a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM messages 
WHERE (sender_id = 3 AND receiver_id = 7) OR (sender_id = 7 AND receiver_id = 3) 
ORDER BY created_at
LIMIT 20
```

I would have composite index: sender_id, receiver_id

What if I created an extra column called "signature" for example, where I would store two ids of the sender and receiver in order of size separated by a dash. For example: 3-7, or 2356-4566, 123-435, etc. And have only that varchar field indexed. Would a query be faster theoretically? if I retrieved it like so:

```
SELECT * FROM messages 
WHERE signature = '3-7' 
ORDER BY created_at
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: i would think a string comparison would be much slower.

Comment: What Daniel says. If the columns are properly indexed, the database should already optimize the crap out of the operation.

Comment: bookmarked... very curious about the answers :)

Comment: Why not just test it? I'm skeptical it'd be meaningfully faster or slower if things are properly indexed, although there may be internal optimizations based on numeric and string indices.

Comment: and you will never enable communication among multiple users? One user sends a message to two other users? Never?

Comment: don't go for `WHERE signature = 3-7`, go for `SELECT * FROM messages WHERE MATCH(signature) AGAINST("3-7" IN BOOLEAN MODE)` **MATCH does a quick search**

Comment: Sounds like a fun experiment. I would create both structures, and use SQL Management studio to analyze the execution plan for each.

Comment: If your ids are known to be less than 65535 You could make a column that stores `((smallest Id * 65536) + largest id)` in an `unsigned int` field. Then you could index that and have a single fast integer comparison. A little unreadable though. I'd at least comment that column.

Comment: Also, don't forget that the `EXPLAIN` and `FORCE INDEX` statements are at your disposal.

Comment: Tested random filled table with 1K unique users and 10M messages - its not a very big table but still as long as indexes are present the speed difference is marginal. How big do you expect your table to be?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM messages 
WHERE sender_id IN (3,7)
AND receiver_id IN (3,7)
AND receiver_id <> sender_id 
ORDER BY created_at
LIMIT 20
    ;
```

IMHO has a good chance of being (marginally) faster.